# Loading a huge amount of data using OJB 1.4

Tags: java, sybase, ojb

I have a `Set<String> catNames` which contains a huge list of cats names (~35K) and I need to load from the database (Sybase) all of those `Cat` objects and put them into a `Map<String, Cat> cats` : each line contain the cat name and the corresponding cat object.

Knowing that I'm using OJB 1.4 (it load the object `Cat` and all of its dependencies like `Food`, `Clothes`...), which is the better way to load such enormous list of cats ?

**Solution 1 :** one access to the database per catName

`cat = getCatByName(catName);` then `cats.put(catName, cat);`
and `return cats;`

**Solution 2 :** one access to the database for all those cat names

`cats = getCatsByNames(catNames);` then

`for (Iterator iterator = cats.iterator(); iterator.hasNext();) {
     cat = (Cat)iterator.next();
     cats.put(cat.getName(), cat);
}`

and `return cats;`

**PS :** `getCatsByNames` uses `criteria.addIn("catName", catNames);`